# Adding data from barcode scanner to DataGridView makes my app crash C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview

I have an app that reads barcode from a OPOS Scanner using `POS for .NET 1.14` and then add it to a `DataGridView`.

My problem is that the application hangs(not in debug though for some reason) after 2-3 scanned barcode, it seems like it hangs when the data added to datagridview makes the vertical scrollbar appear.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
private BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
private DataTable dataTableGrid;

//Reads data from the OPOS barcoder scanner
private async void myScanner_DataEvent(object sender, DataEventArgs e)
{
    ASCIIEncoding myEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    var barcode = myEncoding.GetString(myScanner.ScanDataLabel);
    toolStripStatusLabelBarcodeLetto.Text = "Barcode: " + barcode;
    await Task.Run(() => AnalisiBarcode(barcode)); //Runs on a different thread so the user can scan when the UI is still updating
    CaricaDatiInseriti(); //Should run on UI thread
    myScanner.DataEventEnabled = true;
}

private void AnalisiBarcode(string barcode)
{
//Analyse the scanned barcode and add data to dataTableGrid
}

private void CaricaDatiInseriti() //Load the data created in AnalisiBarcode to DataGridView
{
    if (IsHandleCreated) //To avoid the app to crash if the user scan a barcode when the windows handle is not created yet
    {
         dataGridViewDati.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate //Delegate to avoid cross thread problem
         {
              bSource.DataSource = dataTableGrid;
              dataGridViewDati.DataSource = bSource;
              dataGridViewDati.Refresh();
              dataGridViewDati.PerformLayout();
              AggiornaTotCapiInseriti();
         });
    }
}
```

EDIT:

After more testing the app doesn't hang if I disable all `scrollbars` in `dataGridViewDati`.
I now have my scrollbars disabled,enabled it only when the user click on the grid and then disable them again before updating the grid. It's a workaround but it works.

Comment: what does it crash with?

Comment: It just hangs and crashes when the user click on the UI that at this point is freezed. I don't get any Exception. I updated my question

Comment: Have you checked the windows event log? Normally .NET places there a detailed message...

Comment: @OlafW I just get an AppHangB1 event in Windows Error Reporting

Comment: I fear you will need to go the classic way: Implement a file log and then write for every step you make an entry... e.g. `Log.WriteLog("1")`, 
`Log.WriteLog("2")`

Comment: Edited my question again, after more testing I'm sure the problem is with scrollbars because the app doesn't hang when I disable them